# How to convert python code character to human readable code

Tags: python, google-vision

I am currently using Google Vision API in python to detect Chinese character in an image, but I found google will return python source code (Such as \xe7\x80\x86\xe7\xab\x91) instead of some human-readable string.

How can I convert it to human-readable text with utf-8 format?

---

Thanks all of your answer, may be I post my code is more easily for all of you.
Here is my code, basically I try to convert the whole json return from GOOGLE Vision and save in a json file, however, it hasn't success.

try:
    code = requests.post('https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key='+GOOGLE_API_KEY, data=params,headers=headers)

```
resultText = code.text.encode("utf-8")
outputFileName = image_path.split('.',1)[0]
outputDataFile = open(outputFileName+".json", "w")
outputDataFile.write(json.dumps(resultText))
outputDataFile.close()
```

except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print('Request error')

Thank you

Comment: This is too vague. Show the code that gets and prints that value. And which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Please post your code. I think "converting string of hexadecimals with \x to string" is an interesting problem (and i've answered that below), but it seems odd that a Google API returns such a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
t = '\xe7\x80\x86\xe7\xab\x91'
t = unicode('\xe7\x80\x86\xe7\xab\x91', 'utf8')
# Output: 瀆竑
```

More detailed information about Unicode in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve this by using the below code. Thanks all of you

try:
    code = requests.post('https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key='+GOOGLE_API_KEY, data=params,headers=headers)
    resultText = json.loads(code.text)
    outputFileName = image_path.split('.',1)[0]
    with open(outputFileName+".json", "w", encoding='utf8') as f:
        json.dump(resultText, f, ensure_ascii=False,indent=4)
    f.close()
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print('Request error')

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you have a literal string like `\xe4\xb8\x89` and you want to convert this into the character `三`.

It's very strange that there isn't a straightforward way to do this. The best i can come up with is:

```
s = '\\xe4\\xb8\\x89'
print(bytes.fromhex(s.replace('\\x', '')).decode('utf-8')) # prints 三
```